# Erro ao ler arquivo XML

Tags: php, xml

Bom pessoal, toda vez que eu boto para ler um arquivo XML no meu localhost para retornar alguma resposta do XML, tudo dá certo mas, quando eu hospedo essa página, ela dá erro. O que pode ser?

O erro que aparece é esse:

> Warning:simplexml_load_file(http://painel.foxsolucoes.net/api/VFZSTmVrMTZaejA9KzU=)
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: Connection
>   timed out in /home/plusr582/public_html/tocando.php on line 2
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O
>   warning : failed to load external entity
>   "http://painel.foxsolucoes.net/api/VFZSTmVrMTZaejA9KzU=" in
>   /home/plusr582/public_html/tocando.php on line 2

Comment: Já testaste um XML pequenino? o teu `php.ini`está igual na hospedagem e no teu localhost?

Answer (score 2):

Não parece estar bloqueando, copie este código abaixo

```
$url = 'http://painel.foxsolucoes.net/api/VFZSTmVrMTZaejA9KzU=';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "<xml>here</xml>" );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$xml_arr_Content = unserialize(serialize(json_decode(json_encode((array)$xml),1)));

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($xml_arr_Content);exit;
```

Caso não funcione verifique se não há alguma extensão php faltando na sua maquina.

Answer (score 0):

O link é acessível e carrega normalmente.

Provavelmente o IP do seu servidor pode estar bloqueado.

Não há o que fazer nesse caso, a não ser contactar a administração do site.

Comment: Amigo continuou o mesmo problema. Teria outra maneira de resolver isso?

Comment: atualizei a resposta